# Eclipse Autocomplete not suggesting the method in Spark/Scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I am newbie in Scala & writing a word count program to find the no of occurrences of each unique word in a file using Spark API. Find below the code

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

//Load Data from File
val input = sc.textFile(args(0))

//Split into words
val words = input.flatMap { line => line.split(" ") }

//Assign unit to each word
val units = words.map { word => (word, 1) }

//Reduce each word
val counts = units.reduceByKey { case (x, y) => x + y }
...
```

Although the Application compiles successfully, The issue I have is, when I type `units.` in Eclipse, the autocomplete is not suggesting the method `reduceByKey`. For other functions the Autocomplete works perfect. Is there any specific reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to `reduceByKey` only being available via `implicit`s. That method is not on the `RDD`, but on `PairRDDFunctions`. I had thought that implicit autocompletion was working in eclipse...but I would guess that to be your issue. You can verify by explicitly wrapping units in a `PairRDDFunctions`

Comment: Hi @Justin I tried with explicit Type; val units:PairRDDFunctions[String, Int] = words.map { word => (word, 1) } and autocompletion is working. But it is impractical to do this explicit type. Is my Eclipse setup missing something?. I am using ScalaIDE for Eclipse